# Critical points and absolute extreme values on given interval

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm back with a question! I am working on a homework problem and I got stuck. I'm asked to 1.find the critical points of f on the given interval
2. fine the absolute extreme values of f on the given interval.

$f(x)= x/(x^2+1)^2$ on $[-2,2]$
so I know the first step is to take the derivative. But that's where I get stuck! 
I got $f'(x)= ((x^2+1)^2 -x(2(x^2+1)*2x))/((x^2+1)^2)^2)$

How do I simplify this?
That's my only question, then I know how to find the critical points easily.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please use a title that describes your question.

Comment: For starters, you have a common factor of $x^2 + 1$ in both the denominator and the numerator.

Comment: The denominator is safely positive, don't touch it. The numerator is $(x^2+1)(1-3x^2)$.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=critical+points+of+f(x)%3Dx%2F(x%5E2%2B1)%5E2+on+%5B-2%2C2%5D

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you know how to do the citical points, I'll just simplify:

\begin{align*}
f'(x)&= \frac{(x^2+1)^2 -x(2(x^2+1)*2x)}{((x^2+1)^2)^2}\\
&= \frac{(x^2+1)^2 -4x^2(x^2+1)}{(x^2+1)^4}\\
&= \frac{(x^2+1) -4x^2}{(x^2+1)^3}\\
&= \frac{1-3x^2}{(x^2+1)^3}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: oh you are so amazing!thanks for the help! =]